# Disable button animation for a single application in Win32 C++

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi, animation, button

With this call

```
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETCLIENTAREAANIMATION, 0, (LPVOID)FALSE, 0);
```

I disable the animation of buttons in my Win32 C++ project (no MFC or anything else) that has Visual Styles Common Controls 6.0.0.0 enabled and correctly initialized by calling `InitCommonControlsEx` function. Is there an alternative method to do this? I am asking because I don't want to disable the animation for the whole system but ONLY for my application. The buttons I create are Custom Drawn (not Owner Drawn).
I create a button like this in the `WM_CREATE` message (hwndbutton is defined before as static so that I can share it between all WM messages):

```
hwndbutton = CreateWindowEx(0, L"BUTTON", L"example", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, x, y, width, height, hwnd, (HMENU)button_id, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
```

and I draw it

```
...
case WM_NOTIFY:
{
    LPNMHDR item = (LPNMHDR)lParam;
    if (item->idFrom == button_id && item->code == NM_CUSTOMDRAW)
        {
            LPNMCUSTOMDRAW item_draw = (LPNMCUSTOMDRAW)item;
            if (item_draw->uItemState & CDIS_HOT)
            {
                SetDCBrushColor(item_draw->hdc, RGB(180, 180, 180));
                SelectObject(item_draw->hdc, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));
            }
            else
            {
                SetDCBrushColor(item_draw->hdc, RGB(255, 255, 255));
                SelectObject(item_draw->hdc, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));
            }
            SetDCPenColor(item_draw->hdc, RGB(0, 0, 0));
            SelectObject(item_draw->hdc, GetStockObject(DC_PEN));
            RoundRect(item_draw->hdc, item_draw->rc.left, item_draw->rc.top, item_draw->rc.right, item_draw->rc.bottom, 0, 0);
            return CDRF_DODEFAULT;   // Return would be CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT but I want to keep the text "example" drawn
}
break;
...
```

By "button animation", I mean for example the fading effect that takes place in the button color when you move the cursor over a button and then leave it: I would like it to be colorA when normale state or colorB when mouse is over and not colorA when normal and fade_until_you_reach_colorB when mouse is over.

Thanks

EDIT: I add two gifs
The first is what I want (and I obtain with a previous call to SystemParametersInfo) and the second is the animation I would like to avoid

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDk51.gif)

[What I DON'T want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3MKS.gif)

Comment: You can make your button owner draw, and then draw it using `DrawThemeBackgroundEx`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter thanks for your reply... Anyway, I would like to keep my buttons custom drawn, it it was possible. If you have any adivces, feel free to reply back again :-)

Answer (score 1):

Theme for individual windows and controls can be disabled as follows:

```
SetWindowTheme(hbutton, L" ", L" ");
```

Animation should already be disabled because you are using custom draw. This method will also disable mouse-hover effect.

Normally when you disable a button's theme it may look weird with old 3-D borders on newer systems. You can add `BS_FLAT` to button's style.

Comment: I tried the function you provided and I also tried `BS_FLAT` style but I could not achieve what I meant. For having an example of an application whose buttons are the ones I mean, take a look at Piriform CCleaner ones: when a button is normal, the color is dark blue; when you pass and leave the mouse over it, it becomes lighter for a fraction of a second and then it comes back to the color it had before. I would like that kind of button.

Comment: I can't install another application to see what you mean. I am confused, earlier you said you wanted to disable button's animation, now it seems you want the custom draw button to fade in and fade out on mouse hover. You mean to add animation? To add such animation you have to use your own timer and paint functions, as far as I know.

Comment: Please, see the original question. I finally added two gifs of what I would like to have and what I DON'T want to have.